# Ubuntu server connection failed sometimes for different subnet client

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, vmware

I am using vmware 6.5

Machine-1 Ubuntu server 16.04

```
# The primary network interface dor virtaual Machine-1
    auto ens192
    iface ens192 inet static
    address 172.16.3.133
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    gateway 172.16.3.1
    dns-nameservers: 172.16.3.254 172.16.3.253
```

Machine-2 Ubuntu server 16.04

```
# The primary network interface dor virtaual Machine-2
    auto ens192
    iface ens192 inet static
    address 172.16.3.134
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    gateway 172.16.3.1
    dns-nameservers: 172.16.3.254 172.16.3.253
```

Machine-1 pinging Machine-2 always. There is no connection issue. (same subnet)

My client machine is windows 10 and my network information is like this:

```
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.161.80
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.252.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.160.1
```

I can connect to Machine-1 using Putty. But my connection failed after several minutes. (`Putty error: Network error software caused connection abort`)

So I open Machine-2 using Vmware UI and pinging to Machine-1, then I can connect again from my Windows machine. I mean network interface looks as if it is sleeping for different subnets.

If any client has different subnet, this issue is occured. We can not solve this problem.

Comment: Talk tho the network administrator and ask how the routers are configured.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have any software in Windows 10 that "protects" your network connections like anti-virus or anti-malware as they have been known to interfere with VMWare.

> But my connection failed after several minutes.

By default SSH will often close inactive connections unless you specify that they should be "keep alive"

Comment: We use Sophos protection. But as I specified, If Machine-1 or Machine-2 pings continuously to any machine in local network, the windows client machines connections does not abort.